# Generating a key-pair and encrypt data with this in Mono C#

Tags: c#, mono, cryptography, rsa, monodevelop

I have RSA modulus and exponent, i want to generate a public key with this components. Then i want to encrypt a data with this public key.

So i wrote this function:

```
public static byte[] EncryptRSA(byte[] rsaModulus, byte[] exponent, byte[] data)
    {       
        byte[] response = null;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSAParameters rsaPar = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

        rsaPar.Modulus = rsaModulus;
        rsaPar.Exponent = exponent;

        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaPar);

        response = rsa.Encrypt(data, false);

        return response;
    }
```

but rsa.ExportParameters method takes long time.

```
public RSACryptoServiceProvider ()
    : this (1024)
{
    // Here it's not clear if we need to generate a keypair
    // (note: MS implementation generates a keypair in this case).
    // However we:
    // (a) often use this constructor to import an existing keypair.
    // (b) take a LOT of time to generate the RSA keypair
    // So we'll generate the keypair only when (and if) it's being
    // used (or exported). This should save us a lot of time (at 
    // least in the unit tests).
}
```

As you can see ExportParameters() method is performing RSA key-pair generation which is time consuming operation.

After that i get exception "Private/public key mismatch" at importing RSA parameters.

Comment: Hint: `private const bool PKCS1_1_5_PADDING = false;` to make the code at least readable when calling `Encrypt`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace the export with creating a new object:

```
RSAParameters rsaPar = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
```

with

```
RSAParameters rsaPar = new RSAParameters();
```

That should still be slow in .net but should be fast in mono since it creates keys lazily.

I also strongly recommend using OAEP padding instead PKCS#1v1.5 padding. The latter has weaknesses that can be exploited in practice unless you carefully work around them. So use `rsa.Encrypt(data, true)` not `rsa.Encrypt(data, false)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any clear way of removing the time-out related to generating the key pair. You are probably better off using [FromXMLString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as I don't see any method to generate the `RSAParameters` object an other way.

As for the mismatch, that is to be expected - the private key is still in there. [Microsoft uses a second `RSACryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (check the sample code) to get around this issue.

Comment: And in my opinion the designers of this API require a good kicking. They mix algorithms with keys, public and private keys, encoding/decoding and what not. Don't they have a single designer in there that raises his voice when he sees this kind of crap?

Comment: Other example of such "high level" design is [X509Certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx) class with its PrivateKey member which makes many .NET developers believe that signature is created by a certificate :) I think there are many people who do not like this API but sadly it will probably never get changed because they want to keep it backwards compatible.